# Regular expression that takes all characters with strings without underscore

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a regular expression that takes all characters of a string before the second underscore. It works well: `^[^_]*_[^_]*`
Anyway, I wish to get all the characters of the string even if the underscore is not contained in the string itself.

```
BCA_2_AAA_BCA_1_BBB    the result is BCA_2
10                     the result should be 10
```

Comment: Try making the second part optional: [`^[^_]*(?:_[^_]*)?`](https://regex101.com/r/pEaCtD/1)

Comment: Also, if you have trouble with understanding optional groups, you can use alternation: `^(?:[^_]*_[^_]*|[^_]*$)`.